# Java3d: Moving the camera and animating

Tags: java, java-3d

In my game I move the camera in my KeyBehavior (extends ViewPlatformBehavior)  This works fine but I'd like to be able to move the camera in a more fluid way.  Currently these moves are about 1 meter each and look like a "step".  Any idea how to animate the camera move between the 2 vectors?

```
protected void doMove(Vector3f theMove) {
        // move the main, forward-facing camera
        // get the current location and translate it by the passed in Vector.
        targetTG.getTransform(t3d);
        toMove.setTranslation(theMove);
        t3d.mul(toMove);
        targetTG.setTransform(t3d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I used a transtion Vector and moved the Camera transform in a loop. Works fine. :)